# When to apply jQuery code in a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have the follow backbone view:

```
core.views.Login = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    el: '#main-content-wrapper',

    events:
    {
        'focus #username': 'usernameFocus',
        'blur #username': 'usernameBlur'
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function()
    {
        var html = unlocked.renderTemplate('login', 'core');
        this.$el.empty().html(html);

        $('#username').focus();

        return this;
    },

    usernameFocus: function(event)
    {
        console.log('focus');
        if($(event.target).val() == 'Username')
        {
            $(event.target).val('');
        }
    },

    usernameBlur: function(event)
    {
        if($(event.target).val() == '')
        {
            $(event.target).val('Username');
        }
    }
});
```

The issue I have is that when I do : `$('#username').focus();` : in the render is that the : `usernameFocus` : event has not yet been attached.  There are only two solutions I can think of.

1. Use `setTimeout` - while this option would technically work, I don't consider it a real option
2. Manually apply events in render - Doing this would completely by-pass the event system that Backbone provides which just seems weird.

Does Backbone provide me a way to run jQuery code after all events have been applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to get your event handlers mapped to the events prior to your focus setting code is to call the same binding code that Backbone itself provides. You should be able to call:

```
this.delegateEvents();
this.render();
```

in your initialize and get the effect you wanted.

Comment: This also works and does answer my original question better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just moved that code out of the view's render method and into the router's method that actually generates the view and that seems to be a better place for it anyways.

Comment: That is a good answer in this case because you might have several views and something outside of the individual views should probably be the arbiter of which one should get focus. However, that doesn't answer your original question so I think I'll take a quick shot at that below.